# Can't acess session's value in other page than where was defined with sessvars

Tags: javascript, session-variables

I'm trying to use [this](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) "session" implementation in javascript but browser issues `undefined` when I try to acess it in *other* page. The current is normal, value is preserved even after a refresh. I can see it working as the [example](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessvarsTestPage1.html) shown in the article. I'm using the same JS file as the page and it sill doesn't works. I have no idea how to fix this.

Here's my files:

**a.html**

```
<script src="http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessvars.js"> </script>
<script>
    sessvars.$.debug();
    sessvars.pageCount=sessvars.pageCount||0;
    sessvars.pageCount++;
    document.write('count = ' + sessvars.pageCount);
</script>
```

**b.html**

```
<script src="http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessvars.js"> </script>
<script>
    sessvars.$.debug();
    document.write('count = ' + sessvars.pageCount); // undefined
</script>
```